# UHF algebras of infinite type must be equal in a certain situation

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers with $p\neq 1$, $M_{p^\infty}$ and $M_{q^\infty}$ it's associated UHF algebras of infinite type such that $M_{p^\infty}\subseteq M_{q^\infty}$. Why follows $p=q$?

I have tried to find an answer only using the definition/construction of such 'UHF algebras of infinite types' ( but other approaches are appreciated as well), but I still don't have an answer.  You can describe $M_{p^\infty}$ as follows:

You can write $M_{p^\infty}$ as inductive limit of $$M_{k_1}\xrightarrow{f_1}M_{k_2}\xrightarrow{f_2}M_{k_3}\to\cdots$$
where $k_{i+1}$ is a multiple of $k_i$ and for each i the map $f_i$ is given by $f_i(X)=\operatorname{diag}(X,\cdots ,X)$. 
To the sequence $\{k_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ you can associate a supernatural number $n=\{n_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ by $$n_j=\sup\{r: p_j^r |k_j \;\text{for some j}\}$$ where $\{p_1,p_2,\cdots\}$ are prime numbers enumerated in increasing order (and note that we admit $r$ to be $\infty$). Here, of 'infinite type' means that $r$ is either $0$ or $\infty$.

If $M_{p^\infty}$ is contained in $M_{q^\infty}$, I'm not sure if it's possible to conclude that $p$ must devide $q$ (and if yes, how?). If we can prove this the claim follows ( since $p$ and $q$ are prime with $p\neq 1$, it must be $p=q$).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there is a unital embedding 
$$
 \phi \colon M_{p^\infty} \hookrightarrow M_{q^\infty}.
$$
Denote by $\tau_p$ resp. $\tau_q$ the unique tracial states on these two C*-algebras. Then 
$$
 \tau_q \circ \phi = \tau_p.
$$
If now $x \in M_p \underset{\text{unital}}{\subset} M_{p^\infty}$ is a one-dimensional projection, we get that 
$$
 \frac 1 p = \tau_p(x) = \tau_q(\phi(x)).
$$
Since $\phi(x)$ is a projection in $M_{q^\infty}$ we have that $\tau_q(\phi(x)) = \frac a {q^n}$ for some $n,a \in \mathbb N$. It follows that 
$$
q^n = a p,
$$
i.e. $p \mid q^n$. That means $p \mid q$ and hence $p = q$.

Comment: Note that $M_{p^\infty}$ does not have "one-dimensional" projections; it does have projections with trace $1/p$, so it doesn't affect your argument. But, question: is it obvious that all projections in $M_{q^\infty}$ have traces like that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I had in mind the image of a one-dimensional projection in $M_p \underset{\text{unital}}{\subset} M_{p^\infty}$.  Furthermore, if  you have a projection $x \in M_{q^\infty}$ we may already assume that it lives in $M_{q^n}$ for some $n$, since $M_{q^\infty}$ is the limit of $M_{q^n}$ with unital embeddings $\mathrm{id} \otimes 1_p \colon M_{q^n} \to M_{q^{n+1}} $. But then $\tau_q(x) = \tau_{M_{q^n}}(x)$, where $\tau_{M_{q^n}}$ is the normailzed trace on $M_{q^n}$, i.e. it is given by $\frac{\mathrm{Tr}(\cdot)} { q^n}$ with $\mathrm{Tr}$ the sum over the diagonal.

Comment: I don't really think you can say that a projection in $M_{q^\infty}$ necessarily belongs to the matrix algebras (if you know an argument, I'm interested because I don't know it). But what you can say is that you can always find a projection in the matrix algebra that is close enough; and then they will be unitarily equivalent and so with equal trace.

Comment: thank you and well done! (However, I hope I can proof something like this by myself next time) @André My guess is that the inclusion must be unital, however, I'm not 100% sure and I keep thinking about it. I agree with Martin Argerami that we just can find a projection which is close enough (and that it's not clear why a projection belongs to the matrix algebras). Fortunately, everything works after these changes. Thanks a lot André and Martin.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sure, I was not completely precise.